# Dualboot install failed? Locked out of Windows

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi

You can't imagine how happy I am after I finally managed to install Ubuntu for the 1st time today. But I still need some help to know how to boot into the other side of my schizophrenic computer, i.e. Windows!

The FACTS:

> > AT BOOTING, I access the GRUB menu, with 2 possible Windows 8 bootings (the system + another recovery drive), and both of them are currently dead ends, providing this message : invalid efi file path... Can I fix this?

Before the install, I defragged plus shrunk my 500MB disk from pre-installed Windows 8.
During Ubuntu 12.04 (Daily Build) Install, I shrunk again my Win disk to 64GB, added a 4 GB swap, a 128 GB media disk (to be formatted NTFS later), and used the rest of free place for my EXT 4 Ubuntu disk. Was it wrong to shrink again my Windows disk? Did it damage the access to Win 8?

So you know,

> > My Computer is a Samsung 532U3C, Prior to install BIOS was set to Disabled Fast Boot, Disabled Secure Mode, and UEFI OS.
> >     I have a recovery CD for Windows 8 in my possession, made before the install.

Thanks for your help. Very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try the boot-repair utility described here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I use the 2nd option from a live CD, which is best if you have an Ubuntu Live CD handy (should be the one you installed Ubuntu with).

Comment: I followed your advice and chose option 2. Then Boot Repair worked its magic and provided me with a working WINDOWS 8 UEFI LOADER entrance in GRUB, making both OS accessible. Thanks Scott!!